# Where do some of the app permissions come if they are not specified in the AndroidManifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I have an Android app published in Google Play and it requests Location and Identity permissions but I haven't specified them in my AndroidManifest.xml. Where do they come from? :/

Here is an screenshot of the permissions required:

[image: permissions]

And here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.wizrapp" >

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.rafaelredrado.wizr.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".LauncherActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/RegisterTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/settings_title"
        android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:parentActivityName="com.wizrapp.MainActivity">
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.wizrapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".IntroActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.rafaelredrado.wizr" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".services.GcmIntentService" />

    <receiver android:name=".receivers.UpdateReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:path="com.wizrapp"
                android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".receivers.BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.ConnectivityReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".services.RegisterIntentService" />

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Here's my `build.gradle` too:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wizrapp"
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.2.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:1.3.0'
}
```

Comment: are you using third party libs??

Comment: I'm using this one https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro

Comment: sure this is the only one? Post your build.gradle

Comment: I have editet my question, and I see that it might be due to google play services.. :o